# find the send auto reply emails from outlook

Tags: email, outlook, reply

I have a mailbox for which I set up an auto-reply. Now it seems someone did not get the auto-reply email (telling the receiver that that particular mailbox is not being managed and questions should be send to a different email address). I am wondering where these auto reply emails are stored. They are not in the Sent emails box. Is it possible to find these emails somewhere? Or is there something like a log file where you can see when an auto reply email has been send?